# Python: Selenium: How to write a try - except code to attempt iteration again

Tags: python, selenium

I have a web-scraper which I am fairly happy with, except sometimes it misses iterations because it doesn't load the webpage fully (this is the nature of the website I am scraping. In these instances, I wish for my code to try the iteration again. At the moment, the framework of my code looks something like this:

```
data = []
for i in range(len(links)):
    try:
        driver.get(link[i])
        a = driver.find_elements_by_xpath(#data in here)[0].text
        data.append(a)
        #this is then written to a csv
    except:
        print(i)
```

So at the moment, my code runs and then just lists for me which number instances failed. I then go back and manually input the data.
It would be much nicer for me if instead of doing this, my program attempted the failed instance again, that way I won't have missed data.
Any way I can achieve this?
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

If you want to retry the same `link[i]` several times, you probably need an additional loop. Exactly what kind of loop depends on some details. If you want to keep trying until you succeed (assuming you can be sure that will eventually happen), then a `while True` loop would make the most sense. On the other hand, if you want to limit the number of tries, a `for` loop on a range would be better.

Here's a sketch of an implementation that tries up to three times:

```
max_tries = 3

data = []
for i, link in enumerate(links):   # this is a slightly nicer way to do your main loop
    for t in range(max_tries):
        try:
            driver.get(link)
            a = driver.find_elements_by_xpath("#data in here")[0].text
            data.append(a)
            break                  # break out of the inner loop if we succeeded
        except:
            print("failed to load link", i, "retrying..." if t < max_tries-1 else "giving up.")
```

Answer (score 0):

You could implement an iteration counter and also find out the difference between both lists, after the first try, for your piece of mind :)

```
data = []
intData = []
counter = 0
maxIterations = 2

def Diff(li1, li2): 
    return (list(set(li1) - set(li2)))

while counter < maxIterations:
     for i in range(len(links)):
        try:
            if counter < 1:    
                driver.get(link[i])
                a = driver.find_elements_by_xpath(#xpathstring)[0].text
                data.append(a)
            else:
                driver.get(link[i])
                a = driver.find_elements_by_xpath(#xpathstring)[0].text
                intData.append(a)

            counter += 1
        except:
            print(i)
            counter += 1

# Find differences between first iterations and all consecutive ones
print(Diff(intData, data))
```